# What formula does Mathematica use for PolyGamma function of complex order?

Tags: functions, special-functions

For instance, `PolyGamma` function in Mathematica gives different values than the similar `Psi` function in Maple, which [uses the formula by Espinosa and Moll](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=Psi).

The Mathematica documentation does not give a formula, just [says](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolyGamma.html) that "For arbitrary complex n, the polygamma function is defined by fractional calculus analytic continuation".

I wonder, what exactly formula does Mathematica use? "We use fractional calculus analytic continuation" is too vague.

Comment: Comparing with the [`maple link`](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=Psi) you provided all examples (1)-(11) agree with the `PolyGamma` in Mathematica. In light of this, can you, please, make an effort to explain yourself better? What exactly is your issue?

Comment: @bmf in Mathematica the value for `PolyGamma[-3,1]` is $\log (A)+\frac{1}{4} (\log (2)+\log (\pi ))$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=PolyGamma%5B-3%2C1%5D, numerically 0.708224..., while in Maple it is $-\frac{\zeta(3)}{8\pi^2}$ which is -0.0152242...

Comment: @Anixx in the way you have phrased your question does not make any sense. This is what I pointed out. It's too vague and the examples from the link you attached in the OP all agree between Mathematica and Maple. Try to be more concrete perhaps

Comment: @bmf .With Mathematica I Have: $\psi ^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}(1)\approx 0.481365$, in Maple: $\Psi^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\! \left(1\right)\approx  0.6570016629$ ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I think that my previous comments were clear. I am not saying that there is no discrepancy. I am saying that the question is very poorly phrased and all examples in the link from (1) to (11) are the same in both cases. That's the statement I made and I still think that the question should be edited to be made clear. And also, I am not implying that your example is not valid. I am saying that I don't see it included anywhere in the OP

Comment: @bmf the examples you are referring to, all use order 0.

Comment: @Anixx details that are completely missing from the OP **STILL**. Am I not phrasing myself clearly enough? I am not against the question itself. I think it's written very poorly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `negative` **integer** and `negative` **noninteger** *Mathematica* uses [formula](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042798001927):

$$\psi ^{(n)}(x)=\frac{\int_0^x (x-t)^{-n-2} \text{log$\Gamma $}(t) \, dt}{(-n-2)!}$$

```
 PolyGammaMathematica[n_, x_] := 1/(-n - 2)!*NIntegrate[(x - t)^(-n - 2)*LogGamma[t], {t, 0, x}]
 PolyGammaMaple1[n_, x_] :=(HurwitzZeta[1 + n, x]*(EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, -n]) + Derivative[1, 0][HurwitzZeta][1 + n, x])/Gamma[-n] // N
 PolyGammaMaple2[n_, x_] := -NIntegrate[(Exp[-x t]*t^n)/(1 - Exp[-t])*(Cos[Pi n] + EulerGamma/Pi*Sin[Pi n] + Sin[Pi n]/Pi*Log[t]), {t, 0, Infinity}](*For Re[x]>0,Re[n]>0*)

 Table[{PolyGammaMathematica[n, 1], PolyGamma[n, 1], 
 PolyGammaMaple1[n, 1]}, {n, -4, -1, 1/2}] // N // Chop // MatrixForm (*For negative integer and negative noninteger*)
 Table[{PolyGamma[n, 1], PolyGammaMaple2[n, 1]}, {n, 1, 4, 1/2}] // N //
  Chop // MatrixForm (*For positive integer and positive noninteger*)
```

**EDIT 25.12.2023**

Looks like  **unfortunately**, multiple extensions of the polygamma function exist, that way **Mathematica** and **Maple** uses a different choice.

[Formula](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma2/introductions/DifferentiatedGammas/01/) for **complexes**  fractional order:

$$\psi ^{(n)}(x)=x^{-n} \left(\frac{\gamma -\log (x)+\psi (-n)}{x \Gamma (-n)}-\frac{\gamma }{\Gamma (1-n)}\right)+x^{1-n} \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\,
   _2\tilde{F}_1\left(1,2;2-n;-\frac{x}{k}\right)}{k^2}$$

```
 PolyGammaMathematica2[n_,x_] := x^-n*((EulerGamma - Log[x] + 
 PolyGamma[-n])/(x Gamma[-n]) - EulerGamma/Gamma[1 - n]) + 
 x^(1 - n)*NSum[1/k^2*Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1, 2, 2 - n, - 
 x/k], {k, 1, Infinity}](*For integer n gives "Indeterminate expression"*)

 Table[{PolyGammaMathematica2[n, 1], PolyGamma[n, 1]}, {n, -3, 5, 
  1/3}] // N // Chop // MatrixForm // Quiet

 Table[{PolyGammaMathematica2[n, 1], PolyGamma[n, 1]}, {n, 1/2 + I, 
  5 + I, 1/2}] // N // Chop // MatrixForm // Quiet
```

For more info See [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma2/introductions/DifferentiatedGammas/)

Comment: @Anixx ,I updated my answer.